# useState does not rerender unless I copy the array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In a react-native project I'm using `react-native-camera-roll-picker`. The idea is that a user selects an image and the header changes to something like "x selected". Trying to get this working with hooks. The code is the below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RNCameraRollPicker from 'react-native-camera-roll-picker';
import { Header } from './header';
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';

export const CameraRollPicker = props => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header title={images.length + ' Selected'} />
      <Content>
        <RNCameraRollPicker
          selected={images}
          callback={imgs => setImages(imgs)}
          groupTypes="All"
        />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

When an image is selected the above does not re-render the component.

Now if I change the callback line to:

```
callback={imgs => setImages(imgs.map(i => i))}
```

boom it works. Now I suspected that somehow `setState` doesn't detect a change in the state and thus does not render the component again. I thus thought that I should create a copy of the array (e.g the `map`) and that seemed to do the trick. I'm new to hooks (in fact my first hook component) and I can't see anything explicitly mentioned in the react tutorial explaining this. I'm sure one of you smart people have an explanation for this please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the [`Object.is` comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)

---

And [react-native-camera-roll-picker](https://github.com/jeanpan/react-native-camera-roll-picker/blob/v1.2.3/index.js#L213) calls `callback(selected, image)` with a mutated array (i.e. "the same value as the current state", even if it contains different items inside).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I understand that, however in my case the array that is set to the state changes. I mean the length of the array changes, the contents change and etc.. What I’m not sure I understand but a why the state is considered as unchanged by react.

Comment: it's the same thing as in `a = []; b = a; b.push(1); console.log(a) // [1]` - if you mutate 1 array, there is only 1 array regardless of how many variables point to that 1 array.

Comment: Gotcha the issue is basically that the same array is mutated thus not technically changed. That makes sense and should’ve have been obvious tbh. Anyway thanks